# Spectral radius of the restriction to invariant subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_{X})$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_{Y})$ be two complex Banach spaces such that $X\hookrightarrow Y$ and $X$ is dense in $Y$. Let $T:Y\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator that leaves $X$ invariant, i.e. $T(X)\subset X$. Furthermore, suppose that the restriction $T|_X$ is a bounded operator on $X$. Is it possible to say something about the relation of the spectral radii $r_Y(T)$ and $r_X(T|_X)$? In particular, is it possible that $r_X(T|_X)>r_Y(T)$?

**Remark:** If one restricts the operator to a subspace the point spectrum can only decrease but it's not clear whether this holds for the whole spectrum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let $Y = \ell^1$, let $X$ be those elements such that ${\|x\|}_X = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n |x_n|$ is finite, and let $T$ be the right shift:
$$ T((x_1,x_2,\dots)) = (0,x_1,x_2,\dots) .$$
Then ${\|Tx\|}_Y = {\|x\|}_Y$ and ${\|Tx\|}_X = 2 {\|x\|}_X$.  Hence $r_X(T|_X) = \lim_{k\to \infty} {\|T^k\|}_{X\to X}^{1/k} = 2 $, whereas $r_Y(T) = 1$.